# Как отключить журнал дебага в Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Как отключить огромный вывод дебага при работе со Spring?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

в файле `application.properties` , который в папке `resourses`  пишешь

```
logging.level.root=OFF
```

также могут быть значения `TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, и OFF`

```
logging.level.root=warn  
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug  
logging.level.org.hibernate=error
```

[ссылка на документацию](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels)

Comment: добавил строку logging.level.root=OFF но ничего не поменялось

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework=off или logging.level.имя.пакета=off ... попробуй вместо off поставить warn или error

Comment: Что-то никак(( Может не правильно делаю, не понимаю